# GWT Developer Plugin with forwarded JSP

Tags: jsp, gwt, servlets

In my GWT and AppEngine project, I'm forwarding a JSP in my `Servlet` using the following:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

The JSP contains a the GWT compiled Javascript reference.

The problem is that even though the page loads fine, the GWT Javascript doesn't run. I'm assuming this is because the newly loading file doesn't include the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` part that would normally be there with the GWT Plugin.

Is there a way to get this working ??

**EDIT:** Based on the answers so far, I think I should mention that it works absolutely fine in Web mode. Also, the base URL maps directly to the Servlet in my `Web.xml` so I access the Servlet at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` instead of  the proposed URL at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

Comment: For reference: I haven't been able to check because my app in now crashing for other reasons but from priliminary tests, it appears all the below solutions actually work. I chose the selected answer for its elegance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?gwt.codesvr=` is used on the client side only, by the `*.nocache.js` file, to trigger the load of `hosted.html` instead of some `*.cache.html`, so it must be present in the URL to trigger DevMode, independently of what can be done on the server side.

If your host page is at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/`, then use `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding using RequestDispatcher should not change the URL in the browser. If you see the `gwt.codesvr` parameter in the browser URL, the GWT plugin should be able to find it. So the problem may be somewhere else imo. To be sure, you could temporarily append the URL parameter to the forward call, e.g.:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997").forward(req, resp);
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure that the path to the `*.nocache.js` resolves correctly relative to the host page. Does it work in Web mode ?

Comment: It works fine when I upload to AppEngine... I already tried appending the URL. That doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

In you servlet, why don't you check if the request is local.

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

If the url contains `http://127.0.0.1:8888` or where ever you are running it you can append the `"/index.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"`.
If not, you can leave it is.

Then you could deploy and test the code there too without having to change your code!